# Heat convenction through double pipe

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, pipelines, thermal-conduction, convection

I have a realistic scenario which involves a double contained PP plastic pipe which a section of the pipeline is placed outdoor. What I want to determine if insulation is required at all. The media is 1M Hydrochloric acid and at times the system is flushed with water. The outer pipe can endure temperatures of as low as -10 to -15 degC depending on the wind factor. The media has an initial temperature of approx. 20degC upon leaving the building I have provided a sketch of the how I would approach the situation. However, it has been several years since I have last touched this area of engineering and therefore I am a bit rusty :). How would I approach this?

Outer diameter of inner pipe =  32mm; thickness 3mm
Outer diameter of secondary pipe =  65mm; thickness 6,5mm
Flow of fluid approx 2 m3/h. However there could be a times stationary fluid
Length approx 50m

[image]

Comment: At least one more bit of info.  You did say stationary fluid 50m, but how much length is the section that will be -15C?

Comment: The 50m length could experience this

Comment: What duration would it be stagnant? (How many seconds before it goes to 2m3/h again?) And what is failure condition (something like: fluid gets to 10degC which is  too cold)? Also please edit the answers to these into the question (we can then delete comments to clean it up after)